# Dooes having a drone really let you get certain photographs you couldn't take otherwise, justifying the high price?

Tags: lens, camera

I have around 1000 US$ to spare for gear on my birthday. I need suggestions, do I buy a DJI Mavic Pro Drone and use it as a Camera for filming and stills or I buy 2 lenses for my Canon Camera 1 Ultra Wide and 1 Sigma Art Lens.

Options:
1.) DJI Mavic Pro

2.) Tokina 11-20mm f2.8 and Sigma 18-35mm Art Lens

My gear which I have already:
Canon 80D
Sigma 17-70mm f2.8-f4 OS HSM
Tamron 70-200 f2.8 VC USD
Tamron 150-600mm 
Canon 50 f1.8

My question is does buying a drone really changes your perspective and gives you certain photographs you couldn't have taken earlier and justifies the high price ?
I live in Hong Kong so some prices I quoted may be lower here than in US / UK.

Comment: We can't tell you how to choose between two radically different options; that's a choice only you can make.

Comment: Thanks for your view @PhilipKendall I was looking for more experienced view on Drone Photography

Comment: Equipment recommendations are off topic. But here, it depends on what photos you want to take, and what type of photos you see as the higher priority. That's the only way to answer that question

Comment: We could easily re-phrase this into something that can be objectively answered, such as "What specific capabilities does a drone provide over a hand held camera"

Comment: If you can  Hover A few feet to several hundred feet  above the ground move back-and-forth and up-and-down while taking pictures with your camera then you do not need to drone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is does buying a drone really changes your perspective

Literally, yes — unless you are otherwise able to fly.

> and gives you certain photographs you couldn't have taken earlier

Again, this is almost certainly true.

> and justifies the high price?

Ah, now it *could* justify the high price, but that depends on how importance the above is to you vs. the value of money to you to do other things. That is going to be different for every situation, so only you can answer.

Comment: +1 just for your amazingly written first couple of lines.